# SQL SERVER. Campo booleano de una lista ordenada alfabeticamente

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo una tabla de personas con varios campos como país, ciudad, nombre, años...
Lo que ya tengo es una consulta que, de cada país y de cada ciudad, me saca todas las personas que viven ahí, ordenadas alfabéticamente.

Entonces ahora lo que quiero es un campo nuevo (esPrimero) que diga si esa persona es la primera alfabéticamente hablando. A modo de ejemplo:

```
País      Ciudad     Nombre     Edad     esPrimero

Alemania  Múnich     Gerd       64       Sí
Alemania  Múnich     Tony       23       No
España    Albacete   Antonio    34       Si
España    Albacete   Pedro      32       No
```

No sé cómo incluir ese campo, que sería booleano donde 1 = sí y 0 = no
A ver si me podeis echar un cable. Gracias

Comment: Puedes editar tu pregunta y agregar la consulta que tienes ya

Comment: Puedes hacerlo con un case

Comment: Según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, debes crear la columna `esPrimero` de tipo `BIT`, la cual almacena 1 = Si y 0 = No

Comment: Si adicionas la consulta te podemos ayudar modificandola como la necesites, sin embargo, te doy una idea, en el select puedes adicionar un columna y sobre ella una subconsulta, o un join. No conocemos bien la estructura de su base de datos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Si mostras lo que intentaste hasta ahora, podemos ayudarte a encontrar una solucion.

Answer (score -1):

Podrías considerar usar `ROW_NUMBER()` para obtener el índice de las filas agrupadas por las columnas `Pais`, `Ciudad` para luego ordenarlas por al columna `Nombre`.

```
;WITH TABLA AS (
    SELECT
        INDICE = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PAIS, CIUDAD ORDER BY NOMBRE),
        PAIS, 
        CIUDAD,
        NOMBRE
    FROM PERSONA
)
SELECT
    PAIS, 
    CIUDAD,
    NOMBRE,
    ES_PRIMERO = (
        CASE WHEN INDICE = 1 
            THEN 'SI' 
            ELSE 'NO'
        END
    )
FROM TABLA
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/LTLXE64549)

Comment: No habria que haber esperado a que demostrara que intento algo? digo, se lo venimos pidiendo hace dias...

Comment: @gbianchi a seguir esperando entonces...